# Are there any proofs implying an indescribably large (or just unknown and unbounded) finite counterexample?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

I am curious whether there has ever been a proof which implies the existence of an example or counterexample at some finite value, but one whose size is utterly unknown, and ideally suspected to be very large.

I know there are some proofs that show relatively large numbers exist but we haven't narrowed down where, and even some upper bounds like $e^{e^{e^C}}$. And there's Graham's number, which is the largest number used in a serious proof that I'm aware of, but it's still describable, however abstractly. Since those are all well-defined or at least bounded, they're not what I'm asking for here. Busy Beaver numbers are also not what I'm shooting for.

My original motivation for wondering about this question was in considering the infinitude of polynomial-generated primes; if it turned out that there could only be finitely many primes per any polynomial (does anybody serious consider this a possibility?), it seems to me like the largest primes for most polynomials would have to be laughably or even inaccessibly large, to have somehow completely given no indication yet of that trend whatsoever throughout all the empirical work and heuristics we've amassed.

**If anyone can point me towards any proof where an example or counterexample has been shown to exist, yet no bounds are known for a specific value, I'll consider this answered.**

Comment: Is Busy Beaver number really a math term? That is a real question, as I have no idea either way.

Comment: Hey, I didn't name it. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) (Also, arguably more CS than math, but it applies here.)

Comment: Thank you @Trevor !

Comment: I suppose you want an example where people actually *care* about having an upper bound, and have tried to find one but failed.  There are tons of theorems out there like "there exists $C < \infty$ such that blah blah blah", where nobody has taken the trouble to try and find an upper bound for $C$, simply because there would be no particular use in knowing one.

Comment: @NateEldredge What, you mean like declaring some number exists with a bunch of arbitrary properties (that nobody cares about)? If so, then yeah, probably not really what I'm after.

Comment: I'm thinking of cases where the properties are interesting, but not the value.  E.g. asymptotic results like "there exists $C$ such that $f(x) \le C e^{-x}$ for all $x$", where $f$ is some interesting function.  What's important is that the function decays at exponential rate, but perhaps it doesn't really matter whether it's $10 e^{-x}$ or $10000 e^{-x}$ or what.  One might be able to get a bound by tracing through the proof, but nobody has bothered to do it because it's boring and pointless.

Comment: Goodstein's theorem? The numbers grow so fast that it is unprovable in Peano arithmetic.

Comment: Well, the Bunyakovsky conjecture (stating that polynomials like $n^2+1$ with integer $n$ produce infinite many primes) can be backed up heuristically, but until someone proves that there are infinite many primes of the form $n^2+1$ , we cannot rule out that there are only finite many. Unfortunately, we won't be able to find primes with magnitude say $10^{10^{50}}$ , not even probable primes.

Comment: The largest prime of the form $n^2+1$ could be small enough to find it, but I agree to you that this is extremely unlikely. But, who knows ? We are not secure of surprises , as the Goodstein theorem demonstrates.

Comment: You can get a pretty good snapshot of the situation by picking a prime-generating poly and tallying up primes in a random contiguous batch from somewhere deepish like $10^{10000}$. Then repeat, using other prime-generating polys (say, by selecting each quadratic using random triplets for coeffs $a,b,c$ over a large range). You could do all this, check to see how closely your results match the expected distribution, but you'd find the results are always reasonable and give no indication whatsoever of any tapering off in density.

Comment: ... and that is reason #42 why I find the idea of finite poly primes implausible beyond any doubt. The upshot, to me, is that even if somehow there were finite poly primes, the sort of minimums you'd have to reach to use up a poly's supply of primes would be so absurdly enormous that the relevant numbers would never arise in any remotely realistic or mathematically useful context. So even if they were SOMEHOW technically finite in the end, I suspect we would get along just fine by treating them as infinite.

Comment: @Trevor Concerning Graham's number : The famous Graham-number is an extremely large upper bound used in the proof, the actually needed value is known to be much smaller. This is different in the case of $TREE(3)$ which is used in a graph theoretical theorem and known not to "collapse" like Graham's number. $TREE(3)$ does not just beat Graham's number, it is in a completely different league.